# window.onerror not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, window, onerror

I am trying to add an onerror event to my website.

```
window.onerror = function() {
    alert("an error");
}
```

But all I receive is:

```
notThere();
ReferenceError: notThere is not defined
```

What am I missing?

Browser: Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m

Steps to reproduce:

- add the code to the console.
- add notThere() to the console

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `window.onerror` works in Chrome (see jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/PWSDF/), but apparently not in the console - which makes some sense.

Comment: what sense does it make?

Comment: I guess, it would hijack errors instead of displaying them in the console.

Comment: I assume it's for security and isolation. So the site doesn't have access to what the user is tampering with on the developer console. Not mentioning it would clutter the possible exception capturing or cause undefined behavior catching errors that didn't happen organically on the site.

Comment: So no error that logs using the console can be captured? I'm not getting anything with `window.location.href = "not://anywhere";` ... it just logs to the console and I can't capture it. How many errors are impossible to get like this?

Comment: @RaisinBranCrunch It can capture any exception that did NOT originate from the console (in some sense, the REPL loop acts as its own exception handler).  However, errors that don't throw an exception will not fire an event.  Your example fails because there is no uncaught exception.  Similarly, this code does not trigger an alert: `try {window.location.href = "not://anywhere";} catch{alert("NO");}` .

Answer (score 65):

window.onerror is not triggered when the console directly generates an error.  It *can* be triggered via `setTimeout` though, e.g., `setTimeout(function() { notThere(); }, 0);`

Possible duplicate: [Chrome: Will an error in code invoked from the dev console trigger window.onerror?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534054/chrome-will-an-error-in-code-invoked-from-the-dev-console-trigger-window-onerro)

Answer (score 28):

Some other reasons that you may not be able to handle errors in `window.onerror` (apart from the mentioned ones):

- Another library sets `window.onerror` after you.
- If you are using Angular, errors wont pass through `window.onerror`. You have to handle them using this factory:

  ```
      .factory('$exceptionHandler', function() {
          return function errorCatcherHandler(exception, cause) {
              console.error(exception);
              if (window.OnClientError) window.OnClientError(exception);
          };
      })
  ```

See:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler

http://bahmutov.calepin.co/catch-all-errors-in-angular-app.html